# Java Object Reference Array Initialization

Tags: java, arrays, oop

In java, how do object references in an array initialization work?

For example, this works fine:

```
SomeObject object1;
SomeObject object2;

// ***

object1 = new SomeObject();
object2 = new SomeObject();

SomeObject[] objects = {object1, object2};

// processing objects
```

However, if I put the array initialization at the "***" mark, I later get a NullPointerException when processing the array elements. Why? The array contains object references already, why does it matter if I initialize the said objects before or after initializing the array?

Comment: When you say, `SomeObject[] objects = {object1, object2};` you are saying objects[0] points at the same Object as object1. If object1 is null, then objects[0] is null even if you change object1 later.

Answer (score 1):

> The array contains object references already, why does it matter if I initialize the said objects before or after initializing the array?

When calling `SomeObject[] objects = {object1, object2};` you will get an array whose elements are assigned the *values* of `object1` and `object2`. Note that in Java a reference is just the value of the address, i.e. when you access `object1` before *assigning* it, the value of that reference will still be `null`.

That's why you get null elements in your array when you build it before intializing the references.

Comment: Oh I understand! So then if I initialize the array as in the question and later on say "object1 = object2", objects[0] will still point to whatever object1 used to be, right?

Comment: @BadgerMole exactly. `object1 = ...` only changes `object1` and nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

At the point of `***`, `object1` and `object2` are declared, but have not yet been assigned. In Java, this means that they are both null.

So when you create array with them, you are essentially doing this:

```
SomeObject[] objects = { null, null };
```

Later when you process the elements of the array, you get a `NullPointerException` because, well, you have stored `null`s in your array.